# How can I subscribe to a Github users' new stars?

Tags: github, github-api

I am looking into creating a service that tweets whenever a user stars a Github repository. The [Github Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) API would be ideal, but it only supports webhooks for orgs and repos, not users.

https://api.github.com/users/metaraine/watched provides exactly the information needed, but it is static.

I want to get newly starred repos without having to poll the `/watched` endpoint. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get newly starred repos without having to poll the /watched endpoint. Any suggestions?

Yeah, that's not possible currently. An alternative would be to poll the [Events endpoint for the user](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user) and look for events which indicate that the user starred a repository. But that's still polling.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up parsing https://github.com/metaraine.atom via Yahoo Pipes (which required a proxy, probably because github has a robots.txt) and tweeting with IFTTT.