# GitHub API - `list-events-performed-by-a-user` in webhook form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-api

I know that GitHub repositories can have [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook), for things like the `push` event. However, I needed something similar for users, instead of repositories. I found that I could [list events performed by a user](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user), which is exactly what I need, except for one thing. How can I receive a webhook event whenever this list of events is updated? I **do** have user access tokens for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found a similar SO question to mine, and it had [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303718/8961491). It looks like there is no webhook support for what I was looking for as of right now.